# invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type list struct C

Tags: c, list, malloc, circular-list

I'm trying to implement an replacement algorithm that deals with page faults. So i'm trying to creat a circular linked list using malloc and im getting the following error: "invalid application of `sizeof' to incomplete type`pageInMemory'.following is the code:

```
 typedef  struct {

            int use; 
            int reference;
            int free;
            struct pageInMemory* next;
            } pageInMemory;


            int main()
            {

                int i;
                struct pageInMemory* start, *nn, *temp, *hand;
                start = NULL;

                    for(i=0; i< pNum; i++) 
                    {
                nn = (struct pageInMemory *)malloc(sizeof(struct pageInMemory));
                        nn->use = 0;
                        nn->free = 1;

                        if(start==NULL)
                        {
                            nn->next = nn;
                            start =nn;
                        }

                        else
                        {     // sfhsdifhsdifj sdijfjsd 
                            temp = start;
                            while(temp->next != start)
                            {
                                temp = temp->next; 
                            }

                            temp->next = nn;
                            nn->next = start;
                            start = nn;

                        }   

                    }



                hand = start;
                temp = start;

             while(temp->next != start->next)
             {
                printf("%d\n", temp->use); //hi
             } 


                return 0;// bye
             }
```

so am i not supposed to use malloc this way ?

Comment: When you do a typedef I suggest this syntax to you : typedef struct foo { ... } foo; It's more clear.

Answer (score 2):

change your struct definition as

```
struct pageInMemory{

            int use;
            int reference;
            int free;
            struct pageInMemory* next;
            };
```

to get your code working.
And just for your info [do not typecast void* coming from malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Thank You very much. I kept the same code and just  redefined the strut the way you suggested and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It should be either:

```
typedef  struct pageInMemory_s {

        int use; 
        int reference;
        int free;
        struct pageInMemory_s * next;
        } pageInMemory;

pageInMemory* start, *nn, *temp, *hand;
... 
nn = malloc(sizeof(pageInMemory));
```

or

```
struct pageInMemory {

        int use; 
        int reference;
        int free;
        struct pageInMemory* next;
        };

struct pageInMemory* start, *nn, *temp, *hand;
... 
nn = malloc(sizeof(struct pageInMemory));
```

A third variant would be:

```
typedef  struct pageInMemory {

        int use; 
        int reference;
        int free;
        struct pageInMemory * next;
        } pageInMemory;

pageInMemory* start, *nn, *temp, *hand;
...
```

For this 3rd option you can use:

```
nn = malloc(sizeof(pageInMemory));
```

or

```
nn = malloc(sizeof(struct pageInMemory));
```

This latter variation I feel is very irritating as there is one name for two **different** things:

- The structure definition/declaration `struct pageInMemory`
- The type definition/declaration `pageInMemory`

I would not recommend to use this 3rd option, but the second.

Comment: The 3rd option got the same name for two different things just because you named them that way. I personally think it is the best option, but you should do `typedef struct pim { ...struct pim* next; } pageInMemory.` And then everywhere else in the code, use `pageInMemory` and pretend that no such thing as `struct pim` exists. Then your type behaves consistently with all other types in the language. For example, you would write `node.next = malloc(sizeof(pageInMemory));` and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

`pageInMemory` is itself defined as type. So instead of this,

```
nn = (struct pageInMemory *)malloc(sizeof(struct pageInMemory))
```

Use this,

```
nn = (pageInMemory *)malloc(sizeof(pageInMemory))
```